# T-SQL Convert/Concatenate/Transpose Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have tried numerous SQL fiddles but got nowhere fast. I have the following in a table

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
-------------------
 A   | B    | C
 D   | E    | F
 G   | H    | I
```

I need the output to be

```
 A   | D    | G
 B   | E    | H
 C   | F    | I
```

Please can someone help. I understand a PIVOT might be the best bet?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to google for "SQL Server Rows to columns"? There are numerous solutions already available. And yes, PIVOT is one solution.

Comment: Yes and they gave results such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server where the data within the table is known. For me, it's not known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by unpivotting it, then push it back the other way.

```
with --Build up as we go
--Start with original data
t (Col1, Col2, Col3)
as 
(          select 'A','B','C'
 union all select 'D','E','F'
 union all select 'G','H','I')
,
--Put rownums in there - they'll help
numbered as (
select row_number() over (order by Col1) as rownum, *
from t)
,
--Now unpivot the data, using cross apply.
unpivotted as (
select r.rownum, c.colnum, c.val
from numbered r
cross apply (values (1, Col1), (2, Col2), (3, Col3)) as c (colnum, val)
)
--Now pivot it back again, grouping by colnum
select max(case when rownum = 1 then val end), 
       max(case when rownum = 2 then val end), 
       max(case when rownum = 3 then val end)
from unpivotted
group by colnum;
```

Comment: The values could be anything and not limited to A to I. I just threw some random data in there

Comment: That's okay. You don't need to have `t` defined the same way. And you can rename your `Col1-3` columns however you like.

Comment: So where it says `select 'A','B','C'
 union all select 'D','E','F'
 union all select 'G','H','I')` what would I put there instead?

Comment: Maybe `select * from yourtable` ?

Comment: I hate it when I type something and then realise my stupidity - thanks!

Comment: You're fine. We all get blinded sometimes.